# How to turn off autocomplete but keep hints on in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using Hinterland extension in Jupyter Notebook.

Basically hinterland is auto-completing the names of variables after I type the first 3 letters or so.
I just want it's suggestion/hinting drop down menu thing.

And I've tried going through the Hinterland documentation but couldn't understand a thing.
Please help in turning off the auto-completion but keeping hints on.